# list the rows where data in the column are similar (Python)

Tags: python

I have a table in tsv format. The columns #4 and #5 have some data separated by ','. Data can be any combination of a1, a2, ...a8, b1, b2...b8, c1, c2...c8 or empty cell. I need to find rows where column 4 or column 5 have at least 3 'a' or at least 3 'b' or at least 3 'c'.

For example, If row has data a1, b1 --> skip this row
If row has data b1, b3, b7  ---> show this row in the list

I only figured out how to open file and get to column 4. Not sure how to split values in the cell and compare.

```
#open file
with open("file.tsv") as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter="\t", quotechar='"')
    for row in rd:
        print(row[4])
```

Comment: Most of this stuff is plain-English in python code, so it should be easy to google some decent results. Read up on the built-in functions ```list.count()```, ```split()```, etc.
Also, look up "List slicing".

Comment: if you have strings then use sting functions